# Python tkinter, how to enter text from a button where my cursor is located in a ScrolledText box?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cursor-position

The following code creates a ScrolledText box which the user can type into. They can also choose one of the buttons to enter a Spanish Language character.

```
from    functools import partial
import  tkinter as tk
from    tkinter import scrolledtext

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry('950x700')
root.configure(background='ivory3')

frame_button=tk.Frame(root, background='ivory3')
frame_button.grid(row=0,column=0, pady=2)

def insert_char(char):
    """When the user presses one of the spanish language character buttons
       put the correct character in the textw box. """
    try:
       my_focus = str(root.focus_get())
       if char == "á": 
          textw.insert("end","á")
       elif char == "é": 
            textw.insert("end","é")
    except Exception as ex:
       txt = "ERROR: insert_char(): " + str(ex)
       clear_txt()
       textw.insert(tk.END, txt)    # Write the error text onto the screen
       return(-1)

# GUI Box that the user can either type or paste text to be read into.
textw = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root,width=90,height=21)
textw.grid(row=1, column=0)
textw.config(background="light grey", foreground="black",
                 font="Times 14 bold", wrap='word', relief="sunken", bd=5)
textw.delete('1.0', tk.END)  # Delete any old text on the screen
textw.update()               # Clear the screen.

Button_AA=tk.Button(frame_button,width=4,bg="grey",fg="white",text="á",
                    font="Times 12 bold", relief=tk.RAISED, bd=10,
                    command=partial(insert_char, "á"))

Button_AE=tk.Button(frame_button,width=4,bg="grey",fg="white",text="é",
                    font="Times 12 bold", relief=tk.RAISED, bd=10,
                    command=partial(insert_char, "é"))

Button_AA.grid(row=0,column=0)
Button_AE.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Say the user types in 'Hable con ella.' and they realize it should be 'Hablé con ella.' If they click right after the e and hit backspace I want them to be able to click on the é button to fix the word. The problem is that the é will be placed at the end of the sentence, giviing me 'Habl con ella.é'

How do I get my button to place the char where the curser is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly adding the text to the end. If you want to insert at the insertion cursor, use the index "insert" rather than "end".

```
textw.insert("insert","á")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textw.insert(tk.INSERT,"á")
```

ScrolledText is a type of Text widget, so you can look up the commands for tkinter.Text if you have any questions about it.